# BIND dynamic update trigger shell script

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dynamic

Would like to trigger a shell script to run when a dynamic zone receives an update.
Haven't found any thing about how to make BIND dynamic zone update trigger a shell script.
Can this be done? Anyone know how?
Thanks

Comment: If no hooks exist (and I font know if that's the case), log it and use fail2ban.

Comment: @davidgo: That's some innovative usage of fail2ban. :)

Comment: Maybe with a specific backend instead of default text-based zonefiles one. But it may be an XY problem, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: As the question is. What I am really trying to do is trigger a shell script to run when a dynamic zone receives an update.  Sure there are reactive ways such as monitoring log or zone files etc.  But looking for a proactive way. i.e. for BIND to trigger the script.  The script changes an address that Apache httpd is configured NOT to log to match the address that was updated in the dynamic zone.